# Unable to visualize Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and learning it from [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php).

Consider the snippet,

```
     <div class="container">
        <!--Row with two equal columns-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="demo-content">.col-sm-6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="demo-content bg-alt">.col-sm-6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But i don't see the row divided into 2 columns.Clearly these are 2 different rows. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What size is your Viewport? This only applies to Viewports >= 992px

Comment: @Lars Graubner: it's a normal desktop machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that your window is large enough. Try using `col-xs-6` instead, if you have a small screen.

Comment: it's the same with sm too. You can try it here http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=two-column-layout

Comment: @Shirgill-Ansari: Ok, I updated it. You need to use xs, because the online HTML editor is half-page so very small. This means that only for xs you get the correct layout.

Comment: or zoom out the page to 75% . you can see the result.

Comment: @Shirgill-Ansari: Even in the CodeLab from Tutorial Point? It works there for me. Are you talking about a local HTML file or the online editor?

Comment: xs worked in my screen. Problem is output frame is too small for you.

Comment: Did you try it on the link provided by me at tutorial republic.

Comment: Yes I did. And simply replaced sm with xs and it worked.

Comment: First check your resolution 
http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/
and than check bootstrap media queries 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries
Than you can see which media query is applied to your screen

Comment: @KondukterCRO:  its 1280 x 1024

Comment: So lg works for your screen but in link you provided output is only on half screen so you need to zoom out screen to see grid correctly
ctrl (command) + scroll down is shortcut

Comment: @Darneas: Can you please share a screenshot of the example on tutorial republic of your m/c so as to get a visualisation of it.

Comment: And what happens when you click on little rectangular next to show output button ?

Answer (score 0):

It works in both Google Chrome and Firefox. I guess you are using IE <8, which bootstrap does not supports directly.

In this case you need to use extra .js file, described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support).

Comment: i am using the latest version of Google Chrome